# The dataset for bar graph is not set properly using ng2 charts and ng5-slider in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, chart.js, ng2-charts

I have a range slider and bar graph. I am trying to change the color of bar graph using range slider, i am able to successfully change the color of bar graph using slider, but the data of the bar graph is not shown properly. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wjpkcr

Comment: what do you mean by "not showing properly", very things seems to be fine in your example code

Comment: @Elmehdi The bar chart never shows to the length of its value. it's somewhat truncated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the issue, but you will have to work a little bit on it to be fully functional.
it appears that when you set `[datasets]="getBarChartData()"` the chart is trying to render but is stuck in a loop because the value of the background color is infinitely changing inside `getBarChartData()`, note that you have a two way binding in your slider:

```
<ng5-slider [(value)]='value' [(highValue)]='highValue' [options]='options'>
```

and you can't rely on that to properly update your chart.
What I did is, I added a `valueChange` event to the slider and update the chart whenever a value changes in the slider.

```
<ng5-slider (valueChange)="logValue($event)" [(value)]='value' [(highValue)]='highValue' [options]='options'>
```

I also added ngOnInit() to properly initialize `dataValues`
link to demo: [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-twalet?file=src/app/app.component.html)